# Clarification about 2 lines of code, axios request

Tags: javascript, axios

I stumbled upon this example on the web:

```
  const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId)
    return response.data
```

how would i replicate such a thing?
usuaually my call looks like this:

```
import axios from "axios";
const baseUrl = '/api/toys'; 


    axios.get(baseUrl)
   .then(ok => ok.data)
```

It seems very convenient to pass down arguments to a single const,
how does the chaining happen?

can someone clarify for me how to implement this?

Edit:
The Example i found is in an async function ofcourse, 
the question is not about how to use axios,
but how to chain it like they did.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#example

Comment: i know how to use axios and how to fetch data, thats not my question

Comment: The answer to your specific question is in the Axios' examples. The general answer is in the JavaScript documentation. Read about [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: would u be so kind as to give a code example perhaps? i cant seem to wrap my ahead around it

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

You can only use the `await` key word in an `async` function. Read up in the link above.

To use an async function in a global scope, declare an IIFE:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Like so:

```
(async () => {
    const ok = await axios.get(baseUrl)
    // use ok
})()
```

Comment: so how do i chain in another function? just ok.getUserById? seems off for some reason

Comment: Think of it this way. Whatever your promise resolves to is made available as a argument to the callback function in `.then`. let's say all of your code that follows your promise depends upon that value. Just using promises, you would have to indent all the rest of your code into the scope of that `.then` callback. Using an async function, you declare the variable for the promise to resolve into and then `await` it. You don't chain anything. Anything you can call on `ok` in your promise call back you can call on it after awaiting it in my example.

Comment: If you want to use some data from that axios call in your code that follows, feel free to use ok.data in the next line of my example. If that following code is a promise as well, feel free to declare a var that the promise should resolve into and await that promise. Something like, `const user = await db.getUserById(ok.data.user.id)`. Obviously without me knowing the shape of the data returned, I cannot tell you exactly how your next line should look...